# Why does the agwrite function in the cgraph library unexpectedly fail on any config/platform but Win64 release?

Tags: c, graph, graphviz

I've been trying to get cgraph (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/cgraph.pdf) working so I read and write some graph files. I tried writing some very basic code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <graphviz/cgraph.h>

int main() {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("test.dot", "w+");

    if (fp == NULL) {
       return -1;
    }

    Agraph_t *g;
    g = agopen("test", Agdirected, NULL);

    Agnode_t *signal1;
    signal1 = agnode(g, "Signal1_ON", TRUE);

    Agnode_t *signal2;
    signal2 = agnode(g, "Signal1_OFF", TRUE);

    Agedge_t *link = agedge(g, signal1, signal2, "link1", TRUE);
    agattr(g, AGEDGE, "label", "transitionlink");

    agwrite(g, fp);

    fclose(fp);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

What should be happening is that the file should be written to test.dot. This code works perfectly fine on Win64 release, but fails on Win64 debug, Win32 debug, and Win32 release. I have double checked the .lib files and .dll files settings in visual studio and in the file directories, making sure to copy the release and debug versions of each platform correctly. However, the agwrite keeps causing a "Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error" crash on Win64 debug, Win32 debug, and Win32 release. The weird thing is if I change 
`agwrite(g, fp);` to `agwrite(g, stdout);`, the code works on all platforms/configurations. I am so confused why this is happening. Here is the source file which contains the code for agwrite if that helps: https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz/blob/master/lib/cgraph/write.c

I cannot debug the issue because the source has been compiled into .dlls, and .libs for each platform/configuration.

I appreciate any suggestions/feedback,
Thank you

Edit:

For anyone godly enough to try and get this working on their own system, here are all my binaries, libs, and include files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/o9tjz7txu4m0k5q/AAAnp8Wu99q9IsFN7kvqZP7Ta?dl=0

Edit 2:

The compiler I am using is MSVC 14 on Windows 10.

Comment: It would help to list the versions of compiler/environment you are using

Comment: @M.M: Thanks for the tip. I am using MSVC 14 on Windows 10.

Comment: I finally got it to work using GVC.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using cgraph directly results in an error when trying to use agwrite(). The solution is to use the GVC abstraction layer which comes with the Graphviz C API to do file I/O. Here is the code that worked:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#include <graphviz/gvc.h>

int main() {

    GVC_t *gvc;
    gvc = gvContext();

    Agraph_t *g;
    g = agopen("test", Agdirected, NULL);

    Agnode_t *signal1;
    signal1 = agnode(g, "Signal1_ON", TRUE);

    Agnode_t *signal2;
    signal2 = agnode(g, "Signal1_OFF", TRUE);

    Agedge_t *link = agedge(g, signal1, signal2, "link1", TRUE);
    agattr(g, AGEDGE, "label", "transitionlink");

    gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
    gvRenderFilename(gvc, g, "dot", "test.dot");
    gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);

    agclose(g);

    gvFreeContext(gvc);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Here is the documentation for GVC: https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/pdf/gvc.3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The reason of crashing is described on official Graphviz site:

> This usually happens when the Graphviz library is built using one version of the stdio library, and the user’s program is compiled using another. If the FILE structure of stdio is different, the call to agread() will cause a crash. This is mainly a problem on Windows where we just provide a binary release built with one version of Visual Studio and stdio changes depending on the version of Visual Studio. It can also occur if the user tries to use cygwin or something similar which may also use an incompatible stdio.

https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqAgreadCrash